# Build installer projects from visual studio 2022 command line

Tags: command-line, build, visual-studio-2022, vdproj

Recently I upgraded a project to Visual Studio 2022. I am using command line to build the installer project (.vdproj) using the command something shown below

```
devenv.com <Solutionfile> /build <InstallerConfiguration>.
```

The command used to build file with VS 2019 but when trying to build the same with Visual Studio 2022 seems to be stuck. It seems that everything builds fine but the Visual Studio process does not exit after the project is built and causes the build pipeline to be stalled. I have disabled out of proc build to see if this was causing the issue but it does not help. Any one experience the same issue? I am using the most recent version of visual studio along with the Visual Studio installer project extension. Any other method of building the installer project? I have tried MSBuild command but it does not understand vdproj files.

Comment: Did you find anything in this?

Comment: This has been fixed with the latest release of VS 2022 17.3.6. Works fine for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed with the latest release of VS 2022 17.3.6. Works fine for me now.